# Vue component looping through itself: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Can't seem be be able to figure out this one.
I have a main wrapper component, which uses another component to render the navigation structure.

Navigation can be multi level deep, hence needs to be generated dynamically.

Wrapper looks like this:

```js
<template>
    <nav v-if="this.navigation.length">
        <link-role :collection="navigation"></link-role>
    </nav>
</template>
<script>
    import LinkRole from './Formats/LinkRole';
    export default {
        components: {
            'link-role': LinkRole,
        },
        props: {
            navigation: {
                type: Object,
                default: () => { return {} }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and `LinkRole` component like so:

```js
<template>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="(item, index) in collection" :key="index">
            <a v-if="item.url" :href="item.url" v-text="item.name"></a>
            <span v-else v-text="item.name"></span>
            <link-role v-if="item.items" :collection="item.items"></link-role>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
<script>
    import LinkRole from './LinkRole';
    export default {
        components: {
            'link-role': LinkRole,
        },
        props: {
            collection: {
                type: [Object, Array],
                default: () => []
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

As you can see within `LinkRole` I'm looping over over items in the collection and re-use itself `LinkRole` if there is another level of `items`.

With this approach I'm getting

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not
>   defined.

but cannot figure out what is causing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Recursive-Components) you need to provide a `name` option in your component in order to be able to use it recursively ..

> Components can recursively invoke themselves in their own template. However, they can only do so with the **name** option

```
import LinkRole from './LinkRole';
export default {
    name: 'link-role',
    components: {
        'link-role': LinkRole,
    },
    props: {
        collection: {
            type: [Object, Array],
            default: () => []
        }
    },
}
```